# Debug slow program; Restart from middle

Tags: python, debugging

I have a program which has slow computations and I wish to debug the algorithm. Now it's very tedious to always rerun everything and I'd rather restart from the middle of the program. Can you think of some clever way to achieve this?

The first vague idea is to define checkpoints (where I make a function call) where I save locals and large data with pickle and/or sqlite (sqlite to be able to inspect intermediate data). Later I could try to call the program telling it to restart at a specific checkpoint. However I don't want to split all code chunks between checkpoints just for this purpose.

Has someone a clever idea how to solve this debugging issue?

Comment: Btw, YAML is another way to be able to inspect data. PyYAML can work with python objects just like pickle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A google search pointed me to [CryoPID](http://cryopid.berlios.de/), which might do the job if you're developing on a linux-based system. It claims to be able to suspend a process and save it to a file, and then later restart it, even on a different computer. I've not tested it though.

Comment: Thanks. In a way it does the right thing. Ideally I'd prefer a "simpler" more controllable solution in Python. Often I know which variables I need to restore. Also I actually have to work on Windows :(

Answer (score 7):

Make your program more modular. Ideally, the main block of code should look something like

```
import config
import my_numerics
import post_processing

my_numerics.configure(config.numerics)
values = my_numerics.run()

post_processing.run(values, config.post_processing)
```

You get the idea. It's then easy to make a 'mock' numerics object which returns pre-computed data, and pass that into post-processing.

---

EDIT: I still don't understand. Is the following accurate pseudocode for your problem?

```
for _ in range(lots):
    do_slow_thing_one()

for _ in range(many):
    do_slow_thing_two()

for _ in range(lots_many)
    do_slow_thing_three()
```

That is, you want to interrupt the numerics halfway through their run (not at the end), say at the beginning of the third loop, without having to rerun the first two?

If so, even if the loops don't contain much code, you should modularise the design:

```
input_data = np.load(some_stuff)
stage_one = do_thing_one(input_data)
stage_two = do_thing_two(stage_one)
stage_three = do_thing_three(stage_two)
```

The first way of doing this is transferring data between distinct stages through an implicit interface; namely, the dictionary of local variables. This is bad, because you haven't defined which variables are being used and hence you can't mock them for testing/debugging purposes. The second way defines a (rudimentary) interface between your functions. You now no longer care what `do_thing_one` does, as long as it takes some input data and returns some output data. This means that to debug `do_thing_three` you can just do

```
stage_two = np.load(intermediate_stuff)
stage_three = do_thing_three(stage_two)
```

As long as the data in `stage_two` is of the correct format, it doesn't matter where it came from.

Comment: But as I said, this is not feasible for my program. I have many plain loops which take a long time. I dont want to put every loop into a separate function passing all locals and returning all locals again.

Comment: @Gerenuk: you can't have your cake and eat it too! Either you have a messy program architecture with global state and no well-defined interfaces, or you rewrite and gain the benefits of maintainability, clarity and testability.

Comment: @Gerenuk: I still don't understand why at the very least you can't take all the numerics code into a separate function/module, so that you can get the final data with `my_numerics.run()` or something. You can copy-paste the loops with global state across if it makes it easier.

Comment: You can't just change the question to fit it to your answer. That's missing the point. I repeat myself when I say that parts of code contain like 40 consecutive loops which all perform lengthy operations. So the numerics.run() would have to be split into a lot of chunks. It has nothing to do with modular design if you split every 5 lines of code into a function and write 40 function calls instead which are used only once. And the question how to rerun from the middle still isn't solved. A clever answer could be how to use Python magic.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll take it as an idea to consider. Yet, I wouldn't agree that writing one-time functions for very few lines of codes is good practice. The loops can refer to many different local variables so the interface is not clear cut. And still some thought is needed how to conveniently skip a given number of mini-modules and restart at a specific checkpoint. I was hoping for some Python Magic which does not require me to break up normal code. Something aspect-oriented applicable everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

[Joblib](http://packages.python.org/joblib/) handles result caching in a quite transparent way.  Here is an example, from their documentation:

```
>>> from joblib import Memory
>>> mem = Memory(cachedir='/tmp/joblib')
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.vander(np.arange(3))
>>> square = mem.cache(np.square)
>>> b = square(a)
________________________________________________________________________________
[Memory] Calling square...
square(array([[0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [4, 2, 1]]))
___________________________________________________________square - 0.0s, 0.0min

>>> c = square(a)
>>> # The above call did not trigger an evaluation because the result is cached
```

The calculation results are automatically saved on disk, so Joblib might suit your needs.

Comment: I logged in just to upvote this. It is exactly what I was looking for, for a while already. It can also be used for performing long computations on environments that can kill your processes, for example AWS with spot pricing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Unit Tests**

This is why Unit Tests exist. Try `pyunit` with small "sample data", or `doctest` for extremely simple functions.

**Mini Test-Programs**

If for some reason you really need interactivity, I usually write an interactive mini-program as what is effectively a unit test.

```
def _interactiveTest():
    ...
    import code
    code.interact(local=locals())

if __name__=='__main__':
    _interactiveTest()
```

You can often afford to ignore loading large chunks of the main program if you're only testing a specific part; adjust your architecture as necessary to avoid initializing unneeded parts of the program. This is the reason people might be saying "make your program more modular", and that is what modularity means: small chunks of the program stand alone, letting you reuse them or (in this case) load them separately.

**Invoking Interpreter in Program**

You can also drop down into an interpreter and pass in the locals (as demonstrated above), at any point in your program. This is sort of "a poor man's debugger" but I find it efficient enough. =)

**Monolithic Algorithms**

Been there, done that. Sometimes your workflow can't be modularized any further, and things start getting unwieldy.

Your intuition for making checkpoints is a very good one, and the same one I use: If you work in an interpreter environment, or embed an interpreter, you will not have to deal with this issue as often as if you just reran your scripts. Serializing your data *can* work, but it introduces a large overhead of reading and writing from disk; you want your dataset to remain in memory. Then you can do something like `test1 = algorithm(data), test2 = algorithm(data)` (this assumes your algorithm is not an in-place algorithm; if it is, use copy-on-write or make a copy of your datastructures before each test).

If you are still having issues after trying all the above, then either perhaps you are either:

- using your real dataset; you should just a smaller test dataset for prototyping!
- using an inefficient algorithm.

As a last resort, you can profile your code to find bottlenecks.

**Other**

There are probably powerful python debuggers out there. Eclipse has one I think.

Also I'd personally avoid `reload <modulename>`, which I've always found caused more headaches than it has solved problems.

Answer (score 0):

The idea from [BuildBot](http://www.buildbot.net) might work. It uses python's [reload()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload) to reload changes modules and then it moves state from old to new objects in a semi-clever fashion.

The buildbot process is always running, but it can be signalled to reload from the outside, in which case this happens.

So, if you stored the intermediate results of your algorithms in objects (sort of what [VTK](http://www.vtk.org) does to reduce computation), you could reload and recreate your algorithm objects, have them reload the old data and then write some logic to re-run the computation on those objects if the python module actually did change.

That way, you could have the process re-load itself just if the files on disk changes. Note that if there are syntax or runtime errors, things might be a bit hairy and you may need to restart (unless you can to a try-pass and roll back to the old objects)

So, yeah, checkpoints are needed. But it might not be bad to have such a framework anyhow. :)

Actually, just modularizing the steps will allow you to cache the data to disk instead. That might solve the case. It will definitely help for testing, just like @katrielalex said.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about it and finally I wrote down what I first had only vaguely in mind. Suggesting redesign still does tell how to skip blocks, load cached data etc.:

```
class DebugCheckpoints:
    def __init__(self, data, start):
        self.checkpoint_passed=False
        self.start=start
        self.data=data

    def __call__(self, variables):
        return Checkpoint(self, variables.split())


class CheckpointNotReached(Exception): pass


class Checkpoint:
    def __init__(self, debug_checkpoints, variables):
        self.variables=variables
        self.debug_checkpoints=debug_checkpoints

    def tag(self, tag_name):
        if self.debug_checkpoints.checkpoint_passed or \
           tag_name==self.debug_checkpoints.start:
            self.debug_checkpoints.checkpoint_passed=True
        else:
            raise CheckpointNotReached()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self,exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if exc_type==CheckpointNotReached: # check if the context was supposed to be skipped
            for v in self.variables:
                globals()[v]=self.debug_checkpoints.data[v] # load globals from data
            return True
        else:
            for v in self.variables:
                self.debug_checkpoints.data[v]=globals()[v] # save globals to data
            return False

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
data={"x":1, "w":4} # this is supposed to be any persistent dict
checkpoint=DebugCheckpoints(data, start="B") # start from B, skip block A but still load x and w from data

with checkpoint("x w") as c: # variable x and w is to be loaded
    c.tag("A") # this will force cancellation of this block, but x and w will be loaded from data
    x=1
    w=4
    print("Doing A")

with checkpoint("y") as c:
    c.tag("B") # as the start is B, this tag will no cancel this block
    y=2
    print("Doing B")

with checkpoint("z") as c:
    c.tag("C")
    z=3
    print("Doing C")

print(checkpoint.data)
print(x,y,z,w)
```

This is an easy framework to introduce checkpoints into the code without writing too much. Because merely defining hundreds of one-time function for every little step would probably be coding horror and moreover variables in functions are local (just imaging putting every 5 lines of code into a function). I don't want to return all variables from the block and declare everything global (that's also why a decorator hack to implement a checkpoint framework isn't good).

Maybe I redesign some calls when I try out cases, but I think it's a good start. Not sure what is supposed to go into the with line and what inside the block (like the `.tag`). I didn't manage to put the checkpoint exception into `__enter__`?